# JqueryMobile Cache Ajax issue

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-mobile, browser-cache

I have a strange issue with my jquery mobile application. Below screen shot from Chrome Developer Tools Snapshot.

[image]

Why does my Pages or Scripts are cached even thiugh Have added

```
 $.ajaxSetup ({
            cache: false
        });
```

Also in every ajax call which loads my `ul` > `li` have set `cache:false`.

Kindly let me know how can I overcome this scenario coz of this my Mobile cache is growing on every single click driving me nuts.

Thanks

**Update** :

Every time I click to navigate to another page this scripts get executed :

```
$('body').on('click', '.menuClass', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
var menuid = $(this).attr('id');
if (menuid == '100001') {
    settings.get('setval', function(obj) {
        if(obj.value.tableMode == "1"){
        $.mobile.changePage('categories.html', {
            transition : "slide"
        });
        return false;
        }
        else{
         $.mobile.changePage('index.html', {
                        transition : "slide"
                    });
        }
     });
   }
 });
```

But for somereasons the URL for categories.html loads on every click changing the url to 
below

```
   http://localhost:8080/categories?_=1347279588477
   http://localhost:8080/categories?_=1347279584203
   http://localhost:8080/categories?_=1347279688227
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why cache:false doesn't work but i'm adding a time created string to prevent caching of ajax pages.

Doing this by adding `&ts="+ new Date().getTime()` to end of url .

Here is my usage ;

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "ajax.php?ajax_file=ajax_table_page&ts="+ new Date().getTime(),
       success: function(data){
       ..................
       }
});
```

I also use this to trace ajax errors (you may add after document is ready )

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  error:function(x,e){
       if(x.status==0){
       alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
       }else if(x.status==404){
       alert('Requested URL not found.');
       }else if(x.status==500){
       alert('Internel Server Error.');
       }else if(e=='parsererror'){
       alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
       }else if(e=='timeout'){
       alert('Request Time out.');
       }else {
       alert('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText);
       }
  }
  });
```

Comment: Hi Thanks For that, It doesnt work in my case. Am loading the ajax call on my `pageshow` does that have any effect?